# Passing id values after iteration - Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get a value of a div after an iteration?
For example I have the following code:

```
cats = [
        { name: "Meow", Age: 3 },
        { name: "hKitty", Age: 1}
       ];

for(i=0;i<cats.length;i++){
     var someDiv = document.getElementById("catz");
     someDiv.innerHtml += "<div value="+cats[i].name+" onclick='doSomething()'>"+cats[i].name+"</div><br>";}
```

So I need to use in the function doSomething() the name of each cat (the value of the div) whenever it is clicked by the user.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you working off the file protocol?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm a beginner with javascript, not sure if copying the code in a html file is enough or not.

Comment: Do you click on the file in your computer to run OR do you go to localhost?

Comment: OH...no, i'm not running it on wamp or xampp, straight from my computer. All the small scripts I did until now in javascript worked that way

Comment: Ok, I moved the files in a wamp server and everything works just fine now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just a note, you can get the inner content of the div, without setting the value attribute as well. Just a heads up.

Check out [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/node.textContent). Value might prove to be easier for you, but it's good to at least know.